# WSL2 Android Studio Install Error - Compiler Oracle Error Occured During Initialization of VM

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio, wsl-2

I am not sure where I am going wrong in this.

I am trying to install Android Studio by following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJ0dI2SYHIE&ab_channel=AwesomeDevNotes) .

I basically downloaded Android Studio for Linux from the archive page, extracted it (folder name `android-studio`), and then moved it into my WSL2 folder.

I already installed Java and set the paths in my `~/.zshrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export STUDIO_JDK=$JAVA_HOME
```

But when I went into the `android-studio/bin` and tried running `sh studio.sh`, I get this weird error

```
    CompilerOracle: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.InternalError: Could not create SecurityManager: allow
        at sun.misc.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:106)
        at sun.misc.Launcher.<clinit>(Launcher.java:54)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1444)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1429)
```

I also installed `vcXsrv` and configured its xlaunch config using [this code](https://gist.github.com/androiddevnotes/6dbed5efcdd1b07f22fe267b87acb22a).

Thank you in advance

Comment: Recent versions of Android Studio require Java 17. BTW why do you do this experiment? Android Studio works way easier and with less problems when installed natively on Windows.

Comment: Thanks @Robert! It worked. In my previous company used Mac so I am much more comfortable doing dev using Unix systems. My new company laptop uses Windows and it is too "unpolished" (setup errors/incompatible libraries/different codebases/etc). Right now I need to dev some react native app. So I am trying to use WSL in hopes to make it easier for myself.